# How to mitigate the impact on connected producers and consumers when restarting a Kafka broker?

Tags: apache-kafka

We've got a Kafka 0.9.0.1 cluster, with 4 brokers, a few hundred topics, 20-50 consumers and
10-15 producers.

Often we've got to do changes on the cluster config and we do rolling restarts, with controlled
shutdowns. However, our consumers and producers see a big impact when:

- The broker is shutting down
- The broker joins the cluster again
- The cluster does a rebalance

The type of exceptions the clients are producing are in the range of:

- NotLeaderForPartitionException
- NotEnoughReplicasException
- NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppendException
- TimeoutException
  NetworkException

My question is, is there a way to mitigate the impact, or is it considered the normal way
kafka and the clients operate?

Is any change in the topology of the cluster (partition leader and ISRs) supposed to cause
these exceptions?

Thank you,